# Frequency band pass in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter, fft

I would like to filter out unwanted frequencies and keep an only 60Hz signal.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import rfft, irfft, fftfreq
#
time   = np.linspace(0,1,1000)

in_sig = np.cos(54*np.pi*time) + np.cos(60*np.pi*time)  + np.sin(66*np.pi*time);
high_freq = 62;
low_freq = 58;

freqs = fftfreq(len(in_sig), d=time[1]-time[0])
filt_sig = rfft(in_sig)

cut_filt_sig = filt_sig.copy()
cut_filt_sig[(freqs<low_freq)] = 0
cut_filt_sig[(freqs>high_freq)] = 0

cut_in_sig = irfft(cut_filt_sig)

from pylab import *
figure(figsize=(10, 6))
subplot(221);plot(time,in_sig); title('Input signal');
subplot(222);plot(freqs,filt_sig);xlim(0,100);title('FFT of the input signal');

subplot(223);plot(time,cut_in_sig); title('Filtered signal');
xlabel('Time (s)')
subplot(224);plot(freqs,cut_filt_sig);xlim(0,100); title('FFT of the filtered signal');
xlabel('Freq. (Hz)')

show()
```

[Plotted results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg9pK.png)

As I can see the filtered signal has lower amplitudes at the edges, I assume it could be due to applied rectangular window. What windows would you recommend to use to improve to output?

Comment: With any type of filtering you’ll have edge effects. With Fourier domain filtering this is even worse. You need to ignore the output near the edges of the signal. Grab a longer signal to start with, if necessary.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, great, thank you for the advice, would recommend any other windows to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue likely comes from numpy's [`linspace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). The default mode is to include the endpoint `stop`. So `time` is `0, 1/999, 2/999, ..., 1`. On the contrary, `fft`, handles of signal of length `N` as a periodic signal sampled at `0, T/N, ... , T(N-1)/N`, thus avoiding the redundancy of the endpoint. 
The computed DFT therefore use a frame of length T=1000/999. Hence the frequencies of the DFT are k*999/1000, not k. Since the length of the frame is not a multiple of the period of the signal (1/6s), a problem named [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage) occurs.

To avoid the spectral leakage, the length of the frame can be shortened to a multiple of the period, by removing the endpoint:

```
time   = np.linspace(0,1,1000,endpoint=False)
```

It returns `time` as 0, 1/1000, ....999/1000, handled by the DFT as a frame of length 1, that is a multiple of the period of the input signal (1/6s).

[image: withoutspectralleakage]

If the length of the frame is not a multiple of the period of the signal, the input signal can be [windowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) so as to partly mitigate the effect related to the discontinuity at the edge of the frame, but spurous frequencies still exist.
Finally, the actual frequencies can be properly computed by estimating the frequency of a peak as its mean frequency wih respect to power density. See my answer to 
[Why are frequency values rounded in signal using FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714169/why-are-frequency-values-rounded-in-signal-using-fft/54775867#54775867)