# FFT Frequency Bins and PIC32

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to derive the frequencies of an audio signal using the FFT library available for the PIC32MZ2064DAB176.

I am using the MPLAB Harmony for configuration.

For the sake of testing, two sine waves of frequencies 1002 Hz and 750 Hz are being used. This is done with the help of an online tone generator tool. I have 1002 Hz on one browser window and 750 Hz on another browser window. The output from the audio O/P jack is fed to the microcontroller ADC after a DC bias.

After performing a DC bias of 1.6 V the signal is sent to the 12-bit ADC. The maximum voltage I am expecting is a 3 V P-P, so I guess a DC bias of 1.6 V will suffice.

The signals are sampled at 48 kHz since I will need to read frequencies up to 20 kHz.

The FFT is a 1024 point FFT.

I am able to get the DC value in the 0th index of the frequency bin.

The formula being used to get the frequency value from the bin is
Frequency = index * Sampling Frequency / Number of FFT Points

However, I am getting a high magnitude always in the 1st and the 2nd frequency bins for any value of the input frequency. According to my understanding, for 1002 Hz, the amplitude should be high around the 21st index of the frequency bin and for the 750 Hz signal, the amplitude should be high at around 16th index.

I am enclosing my code, the ADC Harmony configuration screenshot, the result screenshot and the signal input screenshot.

In the code, the array used for the frequency bin is "singleSidedFFT"

Any help in deriving the correct frequency value is greatly appreciated.

```
    /* FFT */
#define N 1024// Also change the log2N variable below!!
#define SAMPLE_FREQ 48000
#define PI 3.14

// Section: Global Data Definitions
APP_DATA appData;

/* ADC */
long count = 0;

/* FFT */
int16c  fftCoefs[N];
int16c *fftc;
int log2N = 10; 
extern const int16c twiddleFactors[];
long int freqVector[N];
int16c sampleBuffer[N]; //initialize buffer to collect samples
long int singleSidedFFT[N];


void APP_Tasks ( void )
{
    /* Check the application's current state. */
    switch ( appData.state )
    {
        /* Application's initial state. */
        case APP_STATE_INIT:
        {
            bool appInitialized = true;

            if (appInitialized)
            {
                int i;
                fftc = &fftCoefs; /* Stores the twiddle factors */

                // zero the freqVector and singleSidedFFT
                for (i=0; i<N; i++)
                {
                    freqVector = 0;
                    singleSidedFFT = 0;
                    sampleBuffer.re = 0;
                }

                // generate frequency vector this is the x-axis of your single sided fft
                for (i=0; i<N; i++)
                {
                    freqVector = i*(SAMPLE_FREQ/2)/((N/2) - 1);
                }

                /* Calculate the twiddle factors */
                DSP_TransformFFT16_setup(fftc, log2N);
                appData.state = APP_STATE_SERVICE_TASKS;

            }
            break;
        }

        case APP_STATE_SERVICE_TASKS:
        {
            /* Trigger a conversion */
            ADCCON3bits.GSWTRG = 1;

            /* Wait the conversions to complete */
            while (ADCDSTAT1bits.ARDY2 == 0);

            if (count < N)
            {
                sampleBuffer[count].re = ADCDATA2; /* fetch the result */
                sampleBuffer[count].im = 0;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                appData.state = APP_STATE_COMPUTE_FREQ;
                count = 0;
            }

            break;
        }

        case APP_STATE_COMPUTE_FREQ:
        {
            APP_ComputeFreq();
            appData.state = APP_STATE_SERVICE_TASKS;
            break;
        }
    }
}


void APP_ComputeFreq(void)
{
    int i;
    int16c dout[N]; //holds computed FFT 
    int16c scratch[N];

    // load complex input data into din
    DSP_TransformFFT16(dout, sampleBuffer, fftc, scratch, log2N);

    // compute single sided fft
    for(i = 0; i < N/2; i++)
    {
        singleSidedFFT = sqrt((dout.re*dout.re) + (dout.im*dout.im));
    }

    LATAbits.LATA6 = ~LATAbits.LATA6;
}
```

I have also tried writing a stand alone FFT function,. The result is the same. 
Here it is..

```
void APP_ComputeFreq_2(void)
{
    int16_t k, t;
    for (k = 0; k < N; k++) 
    { 
        // For each output element
        int16_t sumreal = 0;
        int16_t sumimag = 0;

        for (t = 0; t < N; t++) 
        { 
            // For each input element
            double angle = 2 * M_PI * t * k / N;
            sumreal += sampleBuffer[t].re * cos(angle) + sampleBuffer[t].im * sin(angle);
            sumimag += -sampleBuffer[t].re * sin(angle) + sampleBuffer[t].im * cos(angle);
        }
        singleSidedFFT[k] = sqrt((sumreal * sumreal) + (sumimag * sumimag));
    }
}
```

[MPLAB Harmony ADC Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ30a.jpg)

[ADC Frequency Bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UX0x.jpg)

[Input Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Nni.jpg)

[image: FFT Result 2]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have a large DC value and you are not applying a window function then as well as a high magnitude in bin 0 you'll get a "skirt" from DC up through a number of low frequency bins due to spectral leakage. If you plot the magnitude spectrum you should see better what's going on.

Comment: Oh, I love these kind of questions. However, you might find a better luck on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ due to specifics.

Comment: Surely you would have looked in _all_ the bins to see the whole spectrum?  Clearly you are looking in the wrong ones.

Comment: @Clifford, Yes, I have had a look at all the frequency bins. They are all single digits. Only the bins 1 and 2 have a high value

Comment: I am not familiar with the PIC32 and its ADC but are you sure your sampling is consistent - it looks like you are triggering the conversions in software; given only 20us or so per sample are your sure your code loop tile does not exceed that or that no interrupts will occur that would disturb that?  An auto-triggered sampling and DMA transfer would perhaps be appropriate.

Comment: This has a "not real code" smell about it given the declaration: `long int singleSidedFFT[N];` followed by  `singleSidedFFT = 0;` and `singleSidedFFT = sqrt((dout.re*dout.re) + (dout.im*dout.im));`.  Moreover `APP_ComputeFreq_2()` iterates N times whilst `APP_ComputeFreq()` only iterates `N/2`.

Comment: On line `sampleBuffer[count].re = ADCDATA2;`, the value of 32bit register ADCDATA2 is affected to an `int16 t` which represents a float between -1 and 0.999. Could it be the issue? For instance if bits FRACT of ADCCON1 or  SIGN2 of ADCIMCON1 are set, casting the 32bit register may be incorrect. See section 22.4.3 of http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001344D.pdf . Could you make sure that `sampleBuffer[...].re` is ok?

Comment: Finally, int16c can rapidely saturate. As noticed in [Harmony documentation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Math%20Libraries_v111.pdf), on page 4: Some prescaling may be necessary to prevent unwanted saturation in functions that may otherwise create calculation errors. The component 0 of a DFT of length 1024 is the average of the signal multiplied by 1024, that is the average shifted 10bits to the left. The correct strategy could be to remove the average from `sampleBuffer[count].re` and scale down the resulting signal so that the 10 heavy bits are cleared prior to the DFT.

Comment: 1) Examine your raw data and make sure that you have a valid mapping from ADC counts to a signed number and are not introducing an offset or worse. 2) Run *calculated* sinusoids through the program at various levels and make sure the results are consistent with expectation.

Comment: @Clifford, I am only considering N/2 samples in APP_ComputeFreq() because the second half of the array is the negative side of the signal.

Comment: @Francis, Even though the ADC register is 32 bits, the data is stored from 0 to 11th bit as it is a 12-bit ADC. And even after pre-scaling the input data, there is no change in the results obtained. Well, I am still clueless about where I am going wrong.

Comment: I have an update. I changed the input frequencies to 12.8 kHz and 18 kHz. The high amplitude has moved to the 22nd and 31st bin. Does it mean I have got the sampling frequency wrongly configured? I am attaching the result image in the post.

Comment: @Ted yes, Francis already pointed that out.  Does not explain the invalid uncompilable code you have posted however.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the feedback! If the frequency 12.8kHz is in bin 22, the sampling rate is about 596ksps. It could be explained by a 100MHz clock, but it can't be the FRC clock of 8MHz. Hence, could you check the ADCSEL<1:0> bits of register ADCCON3? Is it 11 for FRC? The default value of 00 maps to PBCLK3. Moreover, the scaling factors in CONCLKDIV<5:0> (ADCCON3),  ADCDIV<6:0> (ADC2TIME) and count  SAMC<9:0> (ADC2TIME) can be used to recompute the sampling factor according to the equation 29-1 on page 436 of the datasheet.

Comment: Solved. The confusion is because of the PIC datasheet. The PIC32MZDA family uC datasheet, the setting for FRC  in the ADCSEL<1:0> is 0x11. However in the ADC specific datasheet (DS60001344B) for the uc, the setting for FRC is 0x01. With the value set to 0x11, the sampling frequency was 625 kHz. With the value set to 0x01, the sampling rate is as per requirement which is 48 kHz. Strangely the MPLAB Harmony configurator is using the register values as mentioned in the family datasheet. I am now able to get the indices of the frequencies. Thanks a lot for all the feedback and suggestions :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Ted uncovered an inconsistency between the datasheet** of the [microcontroller PIC32MZ Graphics (DA) Family](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC32MZ2064DAB176) and **the version B of the specifications** of [12 bit Successive Approximation Register (SAR) Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001344B.pdf)

In both cases the clock source driving the sampling rate of the ADC is controlled by bits `ADCSEL<1:0>` of the register `ADCCON3`.

The datasheet, on page 452, gives the following clock sources:

```
11 = FRC
10 = REFCLK3
01 = System Clock (Tcy)
00 = PBCLK3
```

On the contrary, [the specifications of the ADC, in version B, on page 14](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001344B.pdf) are:

```
11 = System Clock (TCY)
10 = REFCLK3
01 = FRC Oscillator output
00 = Peripheral bus clock (PBCLK)
```

[At the same point, version D of the specifications](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001344D.pdf) states that:

> Refer  to  the  “12-bit  High-Speed  Successive  Approximation  Register  (SAR)”  chapter  in  the  specificdevice data sheet for the ADC Clock source selections.

The MPLAB Harmony ADC configurator complies with this disposition. Nevertheless, adopting the clock settings of the version B solved the sampling issue, suggesting that the family datasheet is not correct.

The sampling rate may also be affected by:

- `CONCLKDIV<5:0> of`ADCCON3` : control clock divider
- `ADCDIV<6:0>` of `ADCxTIME` : additionnal divider to define the clock source of indiviual ADC. Or alternatively `ADCDIV<6:0> of`ADCCON2` for shared ADC.
- `ADCxTIME<9:0>` or `ADCCON2<25:16>`: number of clock ticks.

As the sampling was much higher than expected (625 kHz against 48kHz), the length of the frame (1024 samples = 0.0016s) was comparable to the periods of the input signal (about 1kHz). Most of the amplitude was therefore stored in the first bins of the DFT and applying a window does not solves the problem.

Once the sampling rate is corrected, the DFT features maxima corresponding to the frequencies or the input signal. These frequencies can be accurately identified by applying a window and [estimating the frequency of a peak as its mean frequency wih respect to power density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714169/why-are-frequency-values-rounded-in-signal-using-fft/54775867#54775867)

Comment: Thanks Francis for covering this in detail.