# FFT for 3d sensor signal

Tags: python, fft, sensors

I have 3d-array of accelerator signal data which sampled in 50 Hz meaning that the time step is 1/50=.02. My goal is to compute the main frequency of this sensor using Numpy or Scipy. My question is that should I compute the frequency of each column separately, using multidimensional fft or computing single Vector and then compute fft.

I used the following function to compute the main frequency.

```py
from scipy import fftpack
import numpy as np
def fourier(signal, timestep):
    data = signal - np.mean(signal)
    N = len(data) // 2  # we need half of data
    freq = fftpack.fftfreq(len(data), d=timestep)[:N]
    fft = fftpack.fft(data)[:N]
    amp = np.abs(fft) / N
    order = np.argsort(amp)[::-1]  ## sort based on the importance
    return freq[order][0]
```

Comment: if your device is attached to something a person is rattling about the dominant frequency found in each of the orthogonal axis will be driven from the same wobbling so will be the same freq across all axis ... both of your options should give same resultant freq so comes down to efficiency ... implement both ways and measure battery drain for each method  ...  having a solution using both techniques would bolster confidence the results are valid ... would be good for you to post your findings back here on SO

Comment: For the three options, the results are not the same. Battery is not important here. My question is that these three components of the signals should be treated separately or together in multidimensional fft.

Answer (score 1):

A 3D array of accelerometer sensors produces an array of 5 dimensions: the space coordinates, time and the components of the acceleration.

Taking the DFT over the `time` dimension [image] corresponds to analysing sensors one at a time: each sensor would produce a main frequency, likely slightly different from one sensor to another, as if the sensors were uncoupled.

As an alternative, let's think about taking the DFT over both spacial coordinates and time. It corresponds to writing the compound signal as a sum of [sinusoidal plane waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave):

[image: Image description]

where `Ǹ` is a scaling factor obtained by multiplying the number of points to the number of time samples. In the sequel, I'll drop this global scaling independent from x,y,z,t,k_x,k_y,k_z and w.

At this point, modeling the physics generating this acceleration would be a significant asset. Indeed, using this DFT makes little sense if the phenomenon is dispersive. Nevetheless, the diffusion, elasticity or acoustics in an uniform material are non-dispersive: each frequency lives indepently from the others. Furthermore, knowing the physics is useful as an energy can be defined. For instance, the kinetic energy associated to the wave k_x,k_y,k_z,w writes:

[image: xxx]

Therefore, the kinetic energy associated to a given frequency `w` writes:

[image]

As a consequence, this reasoning provides a physically-based way to merge the pointwise DFTs over time [image]. Indeed, according to the Parseval's identity:

[image]

Regarding practical considerations, substracting the average as you did is indeed a good start. If computing the velocity is considered by multiplying by 1/w^2, the zero frequency (i.e. the average) is to be zeroed, to avoid occurence of infinite or Nan.

Moreover, applying a window prior to computing the time DFT could help limit problems related to  [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage). DFT is designed for periodic signals of periods consistent with that of the frame. More specifically, it computes the Fourier transform of a signal built by repeating your frame again and again. As a consequence, artifical discontinuities may appear at the edges, inducing misleading non-existing frequencies. [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) drops near zero close to the edge of the frame, thus reducing the discontinuities and their effect. As a consequence, it could be suggested to apply a window to the space dimensions as well, to keep the consistency with the physical plane wave decomposition. It would result in giving more weight to the accelerators at the center of the 3D array.

The plane wave decomposition also requires that the spacial spacing of the sensor must be about twice smaller than the expected wavelength. Otherwise, another phenomenon called [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) occurs. Nevertheless, the power spectrum W(w) might be less sensitive to this issue than the plane wave decomposition. On the contrary, if the elastic strain energy is computed starting from  the acceleration, aliasing could become a real problem, because computing the strain requires derivative with respect to space coordinates, i.e. multiplication by k_x, k_y or k_z, and space aliasing corresponds to using the wrong k_x.

Once W(w) is computed, the frequencies corresponding to each peak can be estimated by computing the mean frequency over the peak with respect to power density as in [Why are frequency values rounded in signal using FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714169/why-are-frequency-values-rounded-in-signal-using-fft/54775867#54775867) .

Here is a sample code generating some plane waves of frequencies not consistent with the size of the frame (both time and space). Hanning windows are applied, the kinetic energy is computed and the frequencies corresponding to each peak are retreived.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import scipy



spacingx=1.
spacingy=1.
spacingz=1.
spacingt=1./50.
Nx=5
Ny=5
Nz=5
Nt=512

frequency1=9.5
frequency2=13.7
frequency3=22.3
#building a signal
acc=np.zeros((Nx,Ny,Nz,Nt,3))
for i in range(Nx):
    for j in range(Ny):
        for k in range(Nz):
            for l in range(Nt):

                acc[i,j,k,l,0]=np.sin(i*spacingx+j*spacingy-2*np.pi*frequency1*l*spacingt)
                acc[i,j,k,l,1]=np.sin(i*spacingx+1.5*k*spacingz-2*np.pi*frequency2*l*spacingt)
                acc[i,j,k,l,2]=np.sin(1.5*i*spacingx+k*spacingz-2*np.pi*frequency3*l*spacingt)

#applying a window both in time and space
hanningx=np.hanning(Nx)
hanningy=np.hanning(Ny)
hanningz=np.hanning(Nz)
hanningt=np.hanning(Nt)

for i in range(Nx):
    hx=hanningx[i]
    for j in range(Ny):
        hy=hanningy[j]
        for k in range(Nz):
            hz=hanningx[k]
            for l in range(Nt):
                ht=hanningt[l]
                acc[i,j,k,l,0]*=hx*hy*hz*ht
                acc[i,j,k,l,1]*=hx*hy*hz*ht
                acc[i,j,k,l,2]*=hx*hy*hz*ht


#computing the DFT over time.
acctilde=np.fft.fft(acc,axis=3)


#kinetic energy
print acctilde.shape[3]
kineticW=np.zeros(acctilde.shape[3])
frequencies=np.fft.fftfreq(Nt, spacingt)

for l in range(Nt):
    oneonomegasquared=0.
    if l>0:
        oneonomegasquared=1.0/(frequencies[l]*frequencies[l])
    for i in range(Nx):
        for j in range(Ny):
            for k in range(Nz):
                kineticW[l]+= oneonomegasquared*(np.real(np.vdot(acctilde[i,j,k,l,:],acctilde[i,j,k,l,:])))



plt.plot(frequencies[0:acctilde.shape[3]],kineticW,'k-',label=r'$W(f)$')
#plt.plot(xi,np.real(fourier),'k-', lw=3, color='red', label=r'$f$, Hz')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714169/why-are-frequency-values-rounded-in-signal-using-fft/54775867#54775867
peaks, _= signal.find_peaks(kineticW, height=np.max(kineticW)*0.1)
print "potential frequencies index", peaks

#compute the mean frequency of the peak with respect to power density
powerpeak=np.zeros(len(peaks))
powerpeaktimefrequency=np.zeros(len(peaks))
for i in range(len(kineticW)):
    dist=1000
    jnear=0
    for j in range(len(peaks)):
        if dist>np.abs(i-peaks[j]):
             dist=np.abs(i-peaks[j])
             jnear=j
    powerpeak[jnear]+=kineticW[i]
    powerpeaktimefrequency[jnear]+=kineticW[i]*frequencies[i]


powerpeaktimefrequency=np.divide(powerpeaktimefrequency,powerpeak)
print 'corrected frequencies', powerpeaktimefrequency
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I do not know much about signal processing and what I understood from your answer is that I can compute the fft for each component and then the dominant frequency of the sensor is average of main frequencies (of each component). Is it right? About windowing, I second you and will use that.

Comment: You're welcome! I added a piece of code showing how it could be done.  It is not necessary to compute the DFT over 4 dimensions: computing the DFT over time at each point is sufficient to compute the kinetic energy. But keeping in mind that the resulting power spectrum is related to plane wave decomposition is useful to understand issues related to spacial spacing of sensors and introducing windows over space dimensions.