# I have an array of samples at equal intervals of 25 ms. I want to determine the frequency spectrum for the fundamental

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

From say N=1000 voltage samples at 1 ms sample rate. I need to find precisely with python/numpy the amplitude and angle of the fundamental, which is between 45 and 55 Hz as well as any side bands, that may exist.
Do I need a phase lock loop to do that, or can it be done without ?

Comment: You might be interested by my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714169/why-are-frequency-values-rounded-in-signal-using-fft/54775867#54775867  another potential approach is to use autocorrelation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604595/how-to-extract-features-from-fft/59637162#59637162

Comment: Is your array of samples separated by 1ms (question body) or 25ms (title)?

Comment: sorry samples are at 1m sec intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Your measurement frequency is fundamentally too low and should be more than double your expected event frequency!

measured: 0.025s
event range: 0.0182-0.0222s

more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

Answer (score 0):

A phase lock loop is be a reasonable approach to estimate the frequency etc. of the fundamental. Supposing you have collected the N samples up front, another way to do the analysis is:

1. Apply a window, like `np.hanning(N)`, by multiplying it pointwise with the samples.
2. Compute the spectrum with [np.fft.rfft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html). For a sampling interval of `Ts` seconds, the nth element of the resulting array is the DFT coefficient for frequency `n * N * Ts` in units of Hz (or for the values N=1000, Ts=0.001, simple `n` Hz).
3. Find the bin with the peak magnitude between 45 and 55. The location of the peak gives the frequency of the fundamental. You can interpolate a polynomial ([np.polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)) across a few neighboring bins and find its peak to get a more precise estimate. Magnitude and complex phase of the peak give the amplitude and phase (angle) of the fundamental.
4. Plot the magnitude of the spectrum to look for sidebands.