# Get frequency of a PyAudio block

Tags: python, fft, audio-recording, pyaudio

I'm writing a program that involves PyAudio. I already capture a block using `stream.read()` and get its amplitude using an RMS function from elsewhere on StackOverflow. However, I'd like to also be able to get the (average?) frequency of that block. I think I'll need to use a (fast?) Fourier transform, since my understanding is that it can "interpolate periodic functions," which sounds like exactly what I need. The issue is that I have no idea how I would go around implementing this. Ideally, I'd have a function that takes in a block and spits out a frequency in Hz.

EDIT: Thanks to @MSalters, I now know that this question is not quite possible. Correction: Ideally, I'd have a function that would take a block and spit out an array of frequencies (or other descriptive values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The* frequency probably does not exist - the audio fragment may contain a chord with multiple notes, or percussion instruments. But as you suspected, the FFT is the correct tool. It will tell you the amplitude *for each individual frequency*.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I can make that work. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @rivques: Just pass it to `numpy.fft` ? There's `numpy.fft.fft` which calculates the amplitudes and also `numpy.fft.fftfreqs` which tells you the associated frequency. Usually you take repeated fixed-length (e.g. 20 ms) blocks, in which case there's no need to recalculate `numpy.fft.fftfreqs` for each block

Comment: Indeed, the dft is the way to go. I posted a piece of python code in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714169/why-are-frequency-values-rounded-in-signal-using-fft/54775867#54775867 that could be helpful to compute frequencies, using windowing to attenuate spectral leakage and weighting the dicrete frequencies of the dft to get a better estimate of the frequency.